# Embed a Spin group to a special unitary group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, spin-geometry

How do we embed a Spin group to a Unitary group?

Say a Spin(10) group is a Lie group with $\frac{10 \cdot 9}{2}=45$ Lie algebra generators.

Say a special unitary group SU($n$) has a $n^2-1$ Lie algebra generators.

When $n \geq 7$, we have
$$ 
n^2-1 \geq 7^2-1=48>45
$$

> questions:
>
> - What is the minimal $n$ to find the embedding of SU($n$) $\supset \text{Spin}(10)?$ Is that $n \geq 7$?
> - How do we find such an embedding by an explicit construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: It appears that my answer below is wrong since these half-spinor representations are not faithful. I will sort this out when I have more time to think about it.

First of all, it suffices to study complex representations $\rho: Spin(n, {\mathbb C})\to SL(N, {\mathbb C})$ of complex Spin groups $Spin(n, {\mathbb C})$: The restriction of such a representation to the compact Spin subgroup $Spin(n)$ is automatically *unitarizable*, i.e. the image is contained in a conjugate of $SU(N)$.

A representation $\rho$ is called *spinoral* (or simply spin) if it does not descend to the orthogonal group $SO(n, {\mathbb C})$ (equivalently, $\rho$ is injective). Confusingly, there are also half-spin (or semi-spin) representations: They are also spinoral.

For each simple complex Lie group $G$ irreducible (finite-dimensional) complex linear representations $G\to GL(V)$ are parameterized by *weights* $\lambda$; one writes $V=V(\lambda)$ in this situation (the notation $\rho$ is suppressed). Each weight $\lambda$ is the sum of *fundamental weights* $\omega_1,...,\omega_\ell$, where $\ell$ is the *rank* of the group $G$. For $G=Spin(n, {\mathbb C})$ ($n\ge 5$), $n=2\ell$ or $n=2\ell+1$ depending on the parity of $\ell$. Pierre Deligne in his [Notes on spinors](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/deligne.pdf) observes that among *fundamental representations* (i.e. representations whose weights are fundamental) spin-representations correspond to the nodes on the right of the Dynkin diagram: There is either one such node  (labeled $\omega_\ell$, if $n$ is **odd**) or two ($\omega_{\ell-1}, \omega_\ell$, if $n$ is **even**). In the case of two nodes the corresponding representations  are *half-spin* and they have the same dimension. Thus, it suffices to consider only
$\omega_\ell$  regardless of the parity of $n$. One can verify that the corresponding representations $V(\omega_\ell)$ are the spin representations of the lowest dimension. These representations are also *minuscule* (the reason they have the lowest dimension among all spin-representations) and their dimensions are [computed as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation):
$$
N=dim(V(\omega_\ell))=2^{\ell}, n=2\ell+1,
$$
and, in the half-spin case:
$$
N=dim(V(\omega_{\ell}))= 2^{\ell-1}, n=2\ell.
$$
These are the lowest dimensions in which $Spin(n)$ embeds in $SU(N)$. For $n=10=5\times 2$ (the case you asked about) we get $N=2^{5-1}=16$, higher than you expected.

As for explicit constructions of such representations, you can find them in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_representation#Spin_representations_and_their_weights) or in Deligne's notes.

Comment: thank you very much +1. I learn a lot from your answer

Comment: I would accept in a week if no other better answers

Comment: In the light of https://mathoverflow.net/a/328201/27465 which claims that $Spin(4m)$ has no faithful irrep, I think the "equivalently" in your second paragraph is imprecise. It seems that in that case, the two half-spin representations, although not descending to $SO$, are each *not* faithful, but their kernels are "opposite halfs" of the centre $\mathbb Z/2 \times \mathbb Z/2$ (whereas the kernel of the projection to $SO$ would be skew in there); a faithful rep is given only by their *sum*. (Since $10$ is not divisible by $4$, the case considered in the OP here needs no adjustment.)

Comment: do you happen can comment this as well, math.stackexchange.com/questions/3607058, I believe some version is true?

Comment: Maybe you also know this math.stackexchange.com/q/3610249/141334 ?

Comment: Excuse me -- what is the relation between (,ℂ) and ()? Is the former a complexification of ()? I was asking the () as double cover of $SO(n, \mathbb{R})$. My original question is about $() \supset SU(N)$ for the appropriate $n$ and $N$. Is that relation of the minimal $n$ holds for $(,ℂ)\supset () \supset SU(N)$?

Comment: @anniemarieheart Yes, it is the complexification.

Comment: According to your half-spin case: $N=dim(V(\omega_{\ell}))= 2^{\ell-1}, n=2\ell$; it seems that $n=8$ gives $N=8$, so that means the $$SU(8) \supset Spin(8)$$. But according to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203243/relation-between-su8-and-spin8-and-so8-mathbfz-2, only
 $$SU(8) \supset SO(8)$$
but 
 $$SU(8) \not \supset Spin(8).$$
Is there a discrepancy?

Comment: for the case of whether $Spin(8)$ embedds $SU(8)$ see also: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295711/is-spinn-a-subgroup-of-sun

Comment: Just to confirm the comment by Torsten Schoeneberg, the half-spin representations of groups of the form $\operatorname{Spin}(4n)$ are not faithful, even though they do not descend to $\operatorname{SO}(4n)$ either. Indeed for these spin groups, since the (dual group of the) centre is not cyclic, [no irreducible representation can be faithful](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4203931) (as its weights cannot over $\Bbb Z$ span the full weight lattice). It would be nice to correct this answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hi everyone, very interesting discussion. So, is (8)⊃(8)? or is (8)⊅(8)? thanks!

Comment: hi all see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4216056/955245

Comment: See also here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4217885/955245, for $$
Spin(2 \ell)\subset U(2^{\ell-1}) \tag{1}
$$
I think 

- this eq (1) works for $\ell=5,3,1$ 

- but this eq (1) fails for $\ell=4,2$
So maybe more clarification of Moishe Kohan answer will be helpful... thanks!

Comment: See an answer here https://mathoverflow.net/a/402239/106497, it disagree with the answer given here