# Embed a Spin group into an Orthogonal group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds, spin-geometry

How do we embed a Spin group to an Orthogonal group?

Say a Spin($n$) group is a Lie group with $\frac{n \cdot (n-1)}{2}=$ Lie algebra generators.

Say a Spin(10) group is a Lie group with $\frac{10 \cdot 9}{2}=45$ Lie algebra generators.

Say an Orthogonal unitary group O($n$) has a $\frac{n \cdot (n-1)}{2}=$ Lie algebra generators.

Thus naively, we may attempt to

embed Spin($n$) into O($n$),

or Spin(10) into O(10).

> questions:
>
> - What is the minimal $n$ to find the embedding of O($n$) $\supset \text{Spin}(10)?$
> - How do we find such an embedding by an explicit construction?

I suspect that  O(16) $\supset \text{Spin}(10)?$ But what is the minimal $n$ allowed?

Comment: Yes, it is again 16.

Comment: Thank you -- but how will you show it? the group is quite different.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan, you have an easy argument?

Comment: You should mention this is a follow-up to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3296240/96384. Also, you should brace yourself for the necessity to dive a bit deeper into representation theory to answer such questions than just counting dimensions of Lie algebras.