# Irreducible faithful representation of a simple Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G$ be a connected compact simple Lie group of one of the following types: $A_l$, $B_l$, $C_l$, $D_l$, $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$, $F_4$, $G_2$.
Which one of these admit an irreducible faithful representation?

Links that might help:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328138/non-faithful-irreducible-representations-of-simple-lie-groups?rq=1;

[Lowest-dimensional faithful representations of compact Lie groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308375/lowest-dimensional-faithful-representations-of-compact-lie-groups)

Comment: This is again the discussion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3308375/lowest-dimensional-faithful-representations-of-compact-lie-groups), right? You are not referring to the simply connected group, aren't you?

Comment: Isn't it so that (barring the trivial rep) an irreducible rep is faithful if its injective on the center of $G$? This leads to excluding certain highest weights. The exact set depends on how close to being simply connected $G$ is. In other words, the MathOverflow thread gives the answer.

Comment: Yes it is the same discussion, since one year ago I did not get a precise answer. We may ask eventually $G$ to be simply-connected yes.