# Relation between the $SU(8)$, $U(8)$, and $Spin(8)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

I had read several discussions on these posts on the special unitary $SU(8) \subset SL(8,\mathbb{C})$, also $SO(8) \subset SL(8,\mathbb{R})$, and $Spin(8) \subset Spin(8,\mathbb{C})$.

1. This post " [Embed a Spin group to a special unitary group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3296240/955245) " by @Moishe Kohan says that the $$SU(n) \supset Spin(N), \tag{1}$$  for the case of the even $N$, there is a half-spin or semi-spin representation,
   $$N=dim(V(\omega_{\ell}))= 2^{\ell-1}, n=2\ell$$. So according to [them](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3296240/955245), the $n=8$ gives $N=8$. So
   $SU(8) \supset Spin(8)$.
2. This post " https://mathoverflow.net/q/295711 " by @David E Speyer seems to conclude that
   $$SU(n) \supset Spin(n), \quad n \leq 6$$
   but
   $$SU(n) \not \supset Spin(n), \quad n \geq 7.$$
   Thus $$SU(8) \not \supset Spin(8). \tag{2}$$
3. This post " [Relation between $SU(8)$, and $Spin(8)$ and $SO(8)/(\mathbf{Z}/2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4203243/955245) " by @Marc van Leeuwen seems to conclude that
   $$SU(8) \not \supset Spin(8) \tag{2'} $$
   also obviously
   $$SU(8)  \supset SO(8)\simeq Spin(8)/\mathbf{Z}/2 ,$$
   but
   $$SU(8) \not \supset SO(8)/(\mathbf{Z}/2) .$$

**Question 1** - Obviously eq (1) contradicts with eq (2) and (2').
I would like to know why there is a contradiction on the result between the 1st post "https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3296240/955245" and other two posts. Where should the modification or correction go?

**Question 2** - If we change the special unitary to the unitary group, does that $U(8) \not \supset Spin(8)$ or $U(8)   \supset Spin(8)$?
Here $U(8) \subset GL(8,\mathbb{C})$.

Please correct me if I said something wrong or imprecise. I am a new member so hopefully I can learn more from your feedback! Thanks!

Comment: Basically the answer is that $Spin(8)$ cannot be embedded as a subgroup of $SU(8)$. Moishe's answers presents a convincing lower bound on N such that $Spin(n)$ embeds into $SU(N)$ but it doesn't prove that it works for this lower bound. In the $n = 8$ (and thus $N=8$) case we can see that it fails (as per David's answer in the second link and Torsten's comment in the first) and the map must have a non-trivial kernel. Indeed it is suggested that this would be a problem whenever n is a multiple of 4.

Comment: Thanks for the summary, it counts as an answer (almost). except the $U(8)$ part. in Question 2.

Comment: At this point my knowledge runs out but I think the answer is no as $Spin(8)$ admits no irreducible faithful representations (according to the discussions in the linked posts while $U(8)$ does.

Comment: Since it was supposed to summarise my own conclusion (elsewhere), I took the liberty to edit the last two equations so that they no longer contradict each other.