# $Spin(n) \subset SO(n+m)$ for appropriate positive integer $n,m$?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, differential-topology, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

We know that the spin group embedding $Spin(n) \subset Spin(n+m)$ for any positive integer $n,m$.

Can the universal cover $Spin(n)$ be embedded into some $SO(n+m)$ for appropriate positive integer $n,m$?
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
  &  &  Spin(n+m)\\
          &\nearrow &           \downarrow\\
Spin(n) & \longrightarrow^? & SO(n+m)
\end{array}
$$

The question is about whether the $?$ map can be an embedding  for appropriate positive integer $n,m$? What would be the $n,m$?

p.s. I am interested in $n \geq 3$. Of course $n=2$, we have rather obvious examples...

Comment: Do you want that diagram to commute? Because as long as the image of the diagonal map does not intersect the centre of Spin, you can just take the composition to obtain an embedding, no?

Comment: I only care the embedding  - not sure how that affects the story? please illuminate?

Comment: Then just take any map where the centre of Spin(n) is not mapped to the centre of Spin(n+m) and done.

Comment: sorry but is that an embedding? or just a group homomorphism? I want the embedding... thanks

Comment: The composition is injective unless the image of the first map intersects the kernel of the second map. This is just basic function theory..

Comment: @DavidA.Craven:  Of course, one has to prove that you can find such a map $Spin(n)\rightarrow Spin(n+m)$.  As a hint to the OP:  if you can find a faithful rep of $Spin(n)$, this gives you an embedding $Spin(n)\rightarrow U(N)$ for some possibly large $N$.  Can you then find an imbedding of $U(N)$ into $SO(n+m)$ for $m$ large enough?

Comment: @JasonDeVito The OP already thinks they have a map from Spin to a larger Spin. Depending on this map, they might already have an answer.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven:  Agreed.  However, at least when $m=1$, for $n\geq 8$, the only embeddings share centers, so it may require some more thought by the OP.

Comment: @JasonDeVito Absolutely. $m$ will have to grow fairly quickly.

Comment: There is some answer from n embedding ()→() https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3296484/955245. With this inform can some or all of you contribute answers? many thanks - I want to see solutions explicitly.

Comment: You included a diagram involving $Spin(n+m)$. That makes it seem like you want the embedding $Spin(n) \to SO(n+m)$ to satisfy some additional property, namely that the diagram commutes. Is that what you're asking? If so, you need to specify the map $Spin(n) \to Spin(n+m)$. If it is the standard one, then there is no embedding $Spin(n) \to SO(n+m)$ for which the diagram commutes. If you're free to choose the map $Spin(n)\to Spin(n+m)$, then there may be embeddings $Spin(n) \to SO(n+m)$ for which the diagram commutes. If you don't care about the diagram commuting, then Jason's comment suffices.