# $Spin(2n) \subseteq SU(2^{n-1})$ for $n \geq 5$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, spin-geometry

According to this post [Embed a Spin group to a special unitary group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296240/embed-a-spin-group-to-a-special-unitary-group)

It seems to me that there is an answer proposes that for even integer $2n$:
$$
Spin(2n) \subseteq SU(2^{n-1}). \tag{1}
$$
Here $Spin(2n):= Spin(2n,\mathbb{R})$, while the special unitary group $SU(2^{n-1})\subset SL(2^{n-1},\mathbb{C})$.

For some reason given here https://mathoverflow.net/q/295711/336737, the $n=4$ answer seems to be false. Namely, $Spin(8) \not \subset SU(8)$. I would like to know whether eq.(1) can still be true in other $n$ or in general.

For example,

$n=1$, it is false.

$n=2$, it is false.

$n=3$, it is $Spin(6)=SU(4)$ true.

$n=4$, it is $Spin(8)  \not \subset  SU(8)$ here https://mathoverflow.net/q/295711/336737, so false.

Whether this formula eq.(1) is true for $n \geq 5$?