# $Spin(2n+1) \subseteq SU(2^{n})$ for $n \geq 1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, differential-topology, spin-geometry

According to this post [Embed a Spin group to a special unitary group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3296240/embed-a-spin-group-to-a-special-unitary-group)

It seems to me that there is an answer proposes that for odd integer $2n+1$:
$$
Spin(2n+1) \subseteq SU(2^{n}). \tag{1}
$$
Here $Spin(2n+1):= Spin(2n+1,\mathbb{R})$, while the special unitary group $SU(2^{n })\subset SL(2^{n },\mathbb{C})$.

I would like to know whether eq.(1) can still be true in general.

For example,

$n=1$, it is true $Spin(3)=SU(2)$.

$n=2$, it is true $Spin(5) \subseteq Spin(6) =SU(4)$.

$n=3$, it is $Spin(7) \subseteq SU(8)$? likely true.

Whether this formula eq.(1) is true for any $n \geq 1$? or are there loopholes? like this loophole case here [$Spin(2n) \subseteq SU(2^{n-1})$ for $n \geq 5$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4229239/955245)?