# Fundamental representation of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ from the highest weight method

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Applying the definition of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ corresponding to a Lie group $G$ as the tangent space at the identity $T_e(G)$, one can easily construct the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ corresponding to $SO(3)$ as

$$ \mathfrak{so}(3) = \{ X \in \mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbb{R}):X^T=-X \} $$

i.e. it is the set of $3 \times 3$, real, anti-symmetric matrices. An obvious basis of this space is given by

$$ L_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad L_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad L_3= \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Now, if I was to use Cartan's classification and use the highest weight method, I would write down the basis of my fundamental representation as

$$ L_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad L_y =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & -i & 0 \\ i & 0 & -i \\ 0 & i & 0  \end{pmatrix}, \quad L_z= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & -1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

These matrices are neither real nor anti-symmetric. I am aware that the highest weight method produces *representations* of the Lie algebra, but for the fundamental representation I would expect this to be the trivial case of $ d:\mathfrak{so}(3) \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$ where $d(X) = X$ for all $X \in \mathfrak{so}(3)$, in other words, I'd expect these matrices to agree, or at least be related by a similarity transformation. As these matrices operate on Euclidean space, there can't be a real similarity transformation to relate these two representations.

**My question**

Why does the fundamental representation produced by the highest weight method give us a representation that is complex which is neither anti-symmetric or real as the elements of $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ should be?

Comment: I would assume that the highest weight representations a priori are reps of the *complexification* $\mathbb C \otimes \mathfrak{so}_3$. Further though, that is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb C)$, so I would think the fundamental representation is actually on a $2$-dimensional vector space (and would happen to be the standard rep of $\mathfrak{su}_2 \simeq \mathfrak{so}_3$). In short, where do you get your $L_x, L_y, L_z$ from, and what exactly is the weight you are using as highest weight here?

Comment: So these generators I got from the theory of angular momentum in quantum mechanics. These are the generators of rotations

Comment: And what weight? (And is there a specific source you are using? -- Unfortunately there's quite a language barrier between mathamticians and physicists in this theory.)

Comment: The spin-1 representation from this article: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics) so I believe in mathematical language this would be weight 2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, just for clarity of future readers: the terminology "fundamental representation" is used a bit differently in physics than in mathematics (cf. [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2109949/96384), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3229123/96384), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/444401/96384)). The representation we are looking at here is the irreducible one of spin $1$ i.e. highest weight $2$; most mathematicians would not count that among what they call "fundamental representations" (for them, the algebra in question has only one fundamental rep, the one with highest weight $1$, which is of dimension $2$). Instead, they might call it the "defining" representation of $\mathfrak{so}_\color{red}3$ (namely, on a $\color{red}3$-dimensional vector space).

The next big obstacle is that further, mathematicians' and physicists' conventions on (in particular compact) Lie algebras differ by multiplying with the imaginary unit $i$. Because I am a mathematician, I'll stick with that notation, differing from the one in the [Wikipedia article you cite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins); meaning that for me,

$$ L_x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i & 0 \\ i & 0 & i \\ 0 & i & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad L_y =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0  \end{pmatrix}, \quad L_z= \begin{pmatrix} i & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0  & -i \end{pmatrix}. $$

Actually, this is necessary, because when you define $\mathfrak{so}_3$ as the anti-symmetric real matrices, you are already following mathematical convention, so we have to stay consistent.

Now even if you grant me that, on first sight your question remains: These are neither real nor anti-symmetric. (They are however anti-hermitian, and make me very happy because comparing [some computations I did a long time ago on a bus](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3318978/96384) to this and the higher dimension analogues in that WP article makes me realise that, up to multiplying through with $i$, I did some quantum mechanics without knowing it.)

But now it's conjugation and scaling: With $A:=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}\pmatrix{1&0&i\\0&-\sqrt2 i&0\\1&0&-i}$ and $s(M):=AMA^{-1}$, we have

$$s(L_1)= L_x, s(L_3)= L_y, s(L_2)=-L_z . $$

(How to come up with the above base change matrix: Similar to the computations in step 2 in my answer to to [Explicit isomorphism between the four dimensional orthogonal Lie algebra and the direct sum of special linear Lie algebras of dimension 3.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3708404/96384))

It is not too surprising that the "right" general matrices that come from highest weight theory, i.e. the $L_x, L_y, L_z$ above (in mathematical or physical convention) have complex entries, because the theory relies on *complex* representations of the *complexified* Lie algebra, in this case $\mathbb C \otimes \mathfrak{so}_3 \simeq \mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. What is special for this representation is that there is a similarity transform (the $s$, or rather its inverse, above) which makes it "entirely real" i.e. gives out matrices with all real entries. Of course this would be expected in dimension $3$ because after all we can *define* $\mathfrak{so}_3$ as a certain set of $3\times3$-matrices with all real entries (and that's what motivated your question). But if instead we had written that Lie algebra as $\mathfrak{su}_2$, that would have been surprising: The standard way one defines $\mathfrak{su}_2$ involves complex $2\times 2$-matrices, and there is no way to transform those into ones with only real entries. If I recall correctly, that parity distinction repeats in higher dimensions, i.e. the irreducible representations in even dimensions (for physicists: half-integer spin) are "truly complex" (or actually, "quaternionic" or "hermitian" or "pseudoreal", depending on what terminology your source likes), whereas the ones in odd dimensions (for physicists: integer spin) can indeed be written with real (or I guess in physicists' notation: purely imaginary) coefficients.

Comment: Fantastic answer. You raised a point that I’ve been a bit concerned with, which is: with a similarity transformation one can transform a complex matrix into a real matrix. In other words, in one basis I require representation spaces of $\mathbb{C}^3$ whilst in another all I need is $\mathbb{R}^3$. This seems odd as matrices are representing a basis independent operator, however I suppose these operators always have a 3D invariant subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$ which I could just demand as “the real subspace”?

Comment: If I understand correctly, yes: When you can transform a $n \times n$ matrix with complex entries into one with real entries, that means that there's a subspace of *real* dimension $n$ (inside the complex space $\mathbb C^n$ whose real dimension is $2n$) which is invariant under the operator described by the matrix. If you can do that with every matrix of a given representation, then that entire rep "comes from" such a real subspace. Generally it's quite intricate to figure out which representations have such a "real structure". Compare e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3309009/96384.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. One final thing which still bothers me is that the weights of a representation are real, which are just the eigenvalues of the matrices in the Cartan subalgebra. If I took my C.S.A. to be $\{ L_z \}$ in your answer, it has complex eigenvalues not real ones, why is this?

Comment: Mathematically, weights are linear functionals on the complexified CSA, i.e. $w: \mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb C} \rightarrow \mathbb C$. So the image of any $w\neq 0$ is all of $\mathbb C$. By the root system machinery, there always is a basis $(H_\alpha)_\alpha$ of $\mathfrak{h}_{\mathbb C}$ such that for all weights occuring in representations, the $w(H_\alpha)$ are (not only reals, but) integers. However, these $H_\alpha$ generally are in the *complexified* CSA, not in the one chosen in the real Lie algebra. For compact Lie algebras in particular, the weights evaluated on ...

Comment: ... evaluated on the *real* CSA always give out *purely imaginary* values. And maybe that is the reason why physicists, who seemed to be only interested in the compact case originally, adopted that convention of multiplying through with $i$. If we stick with mathematical notation though, then yes, it is a tell-tale sign that we're dealing with a compact group that all eigenvalues are (if not $0$) purely imaginary. In particular, the eigenvalues of your $L_2$ are $0, \pm i$ as well; that's part of what I meant in writing that we have to change the $L_x, L_y, L_z$ to stay consistent.